# Best way to use insistently() to fetch online files reliably?

Tags: r, purrr, httr

I've got a raspberry pi that I'm using to collect satellite data. The first step it needs is to get information on satellite orbits from https://celestrak.org/NORAD/elements/weather.txt, but the wifi connection the Pi is on is unreliable. I've been using GET() from httr simply as
`satellite_data <- GET("https://celestrak.org/NORAD/elements/weather.txt")`
but I'm looking for a more robust solution to retry if it fails with the time backing off for every unsuccessful try from a few seconds to even a few hours or a day since this is a remote sensor that I can't debug in real time. I've looked at https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/insistently.html but still don't have a good idea of how I'd use it with GET.

Comment: Could you use `while()` loop in conjunction with `Sys.sleep()`?

Answer (score 0):

The best I've done is

```
possibly_get_data <- function(url, n_tries, ...){

     #Set exponential back-off so that each ith request waits pause_base * 2^i 
     rate <- rate_backoff(pause_base = 1, max_times = n_tries)
     possibly_insistent_get <- insistently(GET, rate, quiet = FALSE) %>% possibly(otherwise = NULL)

     possibly_insistent_get(url, ...)
}
```

So with network connectivity I get

```
> library(httr)
> library(purrr)
> library(reprex)
> possibly_get_data <- function(url, n_tries, ...){
+ 
+     rate <- rate_backoff(pause_base = 1, max_times = n_tries)
+     possibly_insistent_get <- insistently(GET, rate, quiet = FALSE) %>% possibly(otherwise = NULL)
+ 
+     possibly_insistent_get(url, ...)
+ }
> satellite_data <- possibly_get_data("http://www.celestrak.com/NORAD/elements/weather.txt", 5)
> satellite_data
Response [http://www.celestrak.com/NORAD/elements/weather.txt]
  Date: 2019-08-18 12:50
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: text/plain
  Size: 9.07 kB
DMSP 5D-2 F14 (USA 131) 
1 24753U 97012A   19228.95808892  .00000036  00000-0  41402-4 0  9995
2 24753  99.0314 236.6619 0008659 358.7096   1.4054 14.15859916154988
NOAA 15                 
1 25338U 98030A   19228.92040895  .00000033  00000-0  32688-4 0  9997
2 25338  98.7447 250.0738 0011550  73.3037 286.9410 14.25926944105431
DMSP 5D-3 F15 (USA 147) 
1 25991U 99067A   19228.94325824 -.00000108  00000-0 -31378-4 0  9993
2 25991  98.9231 193.7199 0008799 249.0096 180.8141 14.16519712 17178
METEOSAT-8 (MSG-1)      
...
```

And without connectivity I get

```
> satellite_data <- possibly_get_data("http://www.celestrak.com/NORAD/elements/weather.txt", 5)
Error: Could not resolve host: www.celestrak.com
Retrying in 1 seconds.
Error: Could not resolve host: www.celestrak.com
Retrying in 3 seconds.
Error: Could not resolve host: www.celestrak.com
Retrying in 7 seconds.
Error: Could not resolve host: www.celestrak.com
Retrying in 1e+01 seconds.
Error: Could not resolve host: www.celestrak.com
> satellite_data
NULL
```

But it doesn't yet handle error responses from the server